# get position of object following a path via script

Tags: scripting

I have an object `obj` following a path, and when I run `obj.location`, it always returns the same value for every frame even though it's moving. How can I get the real position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the matrix world.**

An objects world matrix is calculated for every frame, to position all objects globally in the scene regardless of how it is done be it via constraints, parenting, drivers, yada yada.

To get the global location at frame f

```
context.scene.frame_set(f)
global_location = context.object.matrix_world.to_translation()
```